# How can I access an element in my list, if it is joined by a special character?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a function which checks if a value is in a list, and if so, returns a comment like below:

```
iso_list = ['FR','UK', 'GER']

def bucketing(row):
    if row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' and row['party_other_list'] in iso_list:
        return 'Exempt EU national'
    elif row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' and row['party_other_list'] not in iso_list:
        return 'high risk nationality'
```

The problem is, a few of the rows I want to check have a double value assigned. Eg in the final row below:

| party_other_list |
| --- |
| FR |
| UK |
| UK,RU |

Now, since UK is technically in my list I want the last row to fall under my first condition, however it is part of a dual country here, 'UK,RU'.

How do I capture these rows which have dual components, one of which falls under my list?

Comment: is it a string in each row? what if nationality is not RU?

Comment: Yes, each row contains a string. In the instances where we have a joined row like ‘UK,RU’, I still want this to say ‘Exempt EU National’, because one of those two values is in my list. We only want to exclude entities outside of my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into a list, then use the `any()` function.

```
def bucketing(row):
    if row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU':
        other_list = row['party_other_list'].split(',')
        if any(other in iso_list for other in other_list):
            return 'Exempt EU national'
        else:
            return 'high risk nationality'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Barmar, however I’m afraid this did not work; the rows which contained joint countries with one of the two values in my list, did not return ‘Exempt EU National’. Just to confirm, in the example above ‘UK,RU’,  even though RU is not in my list but I want this to be captured because it has UK next to it, which is in my list.

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/EqDzJz

Answer (score -1):

You can use the isdisjoint method from the sets and the split method from the strings. I also improved the if/else block: the condition row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' is always computed once.

The following solution assumes that 2 countries in party_other_list are only separated with a ','.

```
iso_list = {'FR', 'UK', 'GER'}
def bucketing(row):
    if row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU':
        countries = row['party_other_list'].split(',')  # 'UK,RU' -> ['UK', 'RU']
        # Be careful, I switched the conditions
        if iso_list.isdisjoint(countries):  # True if iso_list and countries are disjoint and False otherwise
            return 'high risk nationality'
        else:
            return 'Exempt EU national'
```